# Generate a list of all unique values of a multi-column range and give the values a rating according to how many times they appear in the last X cols

Tags: google-sheets

As the title says.

I have a range like this:

```
  A      B      C     
 ------ ------ ------ 
  duck   fish   dog   
  rat    duck   cat   
  dog    bear   bear
```

What I want is to get a single-column list of all the unique values in the range, and assign them a rating (or tier) according to the number of times they have appeared in the last X columns (more columns are constantly added to the right side).

For example, let's say:
Tier 0: hasn't appeared in the last 2 columns.
Tier 1: has appeared once in the last 2 columns.
Tier 2: has appeared twice in the last 2 columns.

So the results should be:

```
  Name   Tier  
 ------ ------ 
  duck   1     
  rat    0     
  dog    1     
  fish   1     
  bear   2     
  cat    1
```

I was able to generate a list of unique values by using:

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(B2:ZZ9&CHAR(9)),CHAR(9)))))
```

But it's the second part that I am not sure exactly how to achieve. Can this be done through Google Sheets commands or will I have to resort to scripting?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my knowledge is not enough to build an array-formula but I can explain how I get it per cell and then expanded a range from it.

Part 1: count the number of nonempty columns (assuming that if column has something on the second row, then it's filled.

```
COUNTA( FILTER( Sheet1!$B$2:$Z$2 , NOT( ISBLANK( Sheet1!$B$2:$Z$2 ) ) ) )
```

Part 2: build a range for the last two filled columns:

```
OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2, 0, COUNTA( ... )-1, 99, 2)
```

Part 3: use `COUNTIF` to count how many values of "bear" we meet there (here we can pass a cell-reference instead) :

```
COUNTIF(OFFSET( ... ), "bear")
```

I built a sample spreadsheet that gets the results, here's the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13QHKccgMqokDikQvQJdOwyfJ_3D_7TCmjYh1LwI2-Xo/edit?usp=sharing) (*I know external links are bad, but there's no other choice to show the reproducible example*).

Sheet1 contains the data, Sheet2 contains the counts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using both script and the formula.

---

**Normalize the data**

Script is the easiest way to normalize data. It will convert your columns into single column data:

```
/**
 * converts columns into one column.
 *
 * @param {data} input the range.
 * @return Column number, Row number, Value.
 * @customfunction
 */
function normalizeData(data) {
  var normalData = [];
  var line = [];
  var dataLine = [];
  // headers
  dataLine.push('Row');
  dataLine.push('Column');
  dataLine.push('Data'); 
  normalData.push(dataLine);
  // write data
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    line = data[i];    
    for (var j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
      dataLine = [];
      dataLine.push(i + 1);
      dataLine.push(j + 1);
      dataLine.push(line[j]); 
      normalData.push(dataLine);
    }     
  }
  return normalData;
}
```

Test it:

1. Go to the script editor: Tools → Editor (or in Chrome browser: [Alt → T → E])
2. After pasting this code into the script editor, use it as simple formula: `=normalizeData(data!A2:C4)`

You will get the resulting table:

```
Row Column  Data
  1      1  duck
  1      2  fish
  1      3  dog
  2      1  rat
  2      2  duck
  2      3  cat
  3      1  dog
  3      2  bear
  3      3  bear
```

---

Then use it to make further calculations. There are a couple of ways to do it. One way is to use extra column with criteria, in column D paste this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((B2:B>1)*1)
```

it will check if column number is bigger then 1 and return ones and zeros.

Then make simple query formula:

```
=QUERY({A:D},"select Col3, sum(Col4) where Col1 > 0 group by Col3")
```

and get the desired output.

Comment: I tried to implement this. The one thing that it doesn't seem to do is the rating. For example, if I have a total of two columns, and column A & B have the word rat, then the tier of rat should be one. But if I add a column C that doesn't have rat, the tier of rat should go down once. So what it seems to be missing is a way to specify how many columns from the rightmost it will read in order to determine a tier.

Comment: If you mean expanding range, when new column is added, try using formula INDIRECT: `=normalizeData(indirect("data!A2:"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(data!A:A),COUNTA(data!1:1),4)))`